# The path is not of a legal form

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

When I try to run this application it says:"The path is not of a legal form.". It's a warning and it says there is something wrong with:"fileSystemWatcher1.IncludeSubdirectories = true;" when I click on browse. When i click on browse for the 2nd filewatcher it does exactly the same. ( I have 2 browse buttons to watch 2 directories ) I gave the filewatchers no starting path but when i do give them a starting path, it works. I dont want that. Please help me.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private bool pause = false;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }


    // The lines with performed actions of a file
    private void fileSystemWatcher1_Created(object sender, System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!pause)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add("File Created> " + e.FullPath + " -Date:" + DateTime.Now);
        }
    }

    private void fileSystemWatcher1_Changed(object sender, System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!pause)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add("File Changed> " + e.FullPath + " -Date:" + DateTime.Now);
        }
    }
    private void fileSystemWatcher1_Deleted(object sender, System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!pause)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add("File Deleted> " + e.FullPath + " -Date:" + DateTime.Now);
        }
    }

    private void fileSystemWatcher1_Renamed(object sender, System.IO.RenamedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!pause)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add("File Renamed> " + e.FullPath + " -Date:" + DateTime.Now);
        }
    }

    private void fileSystemWatcher2_Changed(object sender, System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!pause)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add("File Changed> " + e.FullPath + " -Date:" + DateTime.Now);
        }
    }

    private void fileSystemWatcher2_Created(object sender, System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!pause)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add("File Created> " + e.FullPath + " -Date:" + DateTime.Now);
        }
    }

    private void fileSystemWatcher2_Deleted(object sender, System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!pause)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add("File Deleted> " + e.FullPath + " -Date:" + DateTime.Now);
        }
    }

    private void fileSystemWatcher2_Renamed(object sender, System.IO.RenamedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!pause)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add("File Renamed> " + e.FullPath + " -Date:" + DateTime.Now);
        }
    }

    //1st directory
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        fileSystemWatcher1.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
        DialogResult resDialog = dlgOpenDir.ShowDialog();
        if (resDialog.ToString() == "OK")
        {
            fileSystemWatcher1.Path = dlgOpenDir.SelectedPath;
            textBox1.Text = dlgOpenDir.SelectedPath;
        }
    }
    //2nd directory
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        fileSystemWatcher2.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
        DialogResult resDialog = dlgOpenDir.ShowDialog();
        if (resDialog.ToString() == "OK")
        {
            fileSystemWatcher2.Path = dlgOpenDir.SelectedPath;
            textBox2.Text = dlgOpenDir.SelectedPath;
        }
    }
    //log
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DialogResult resDialog = dlgSaveFile.ShowDialog();
        if (resDialog.ToString() == "OK")
        {
            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(dlgSaveFile.FileName);
            StreamWriter sw = fi.CreateText();
            foreach (string sItem in listBox1.Items)
            {
                sw.WriteLine(sItem);
            }
            sw.Close();
        }
    }
    //pause watching
    private void pause_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!pause)
        {
            pause = true;
            pause_button.Text = "Unpause";
        }
        else
        {
            pause = false;
            pause_button.Text = "Pause Watching";
        }
    }
    //clear listbox
    private void clear_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Clear(); 
    }
}
```

}

Comment: On what line does it crash?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just a wild guess, but perhaps you need to set `EnableRaisingEvents` to false before you change `IncludeSubdirectories`, and the `Path`? Like this:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dlgOpenDir.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        fileSystemWatcher1.EnableRaisingEvents = false;  // Stop watching
        fileSystemWatcher1.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
        fileSystemWatcher1.Path = dlgOpenDir.SelectedPath;
        textBox1.Text = dlgOpenDir.SelectedPath;
        fileSystemWatcher1.EnableRaisingEvents = true;   // Begin watching
    }
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x7t1d0ky.aspx

Answer (score 2):

The path probably contains invalid characters. See the [MSDN documentation on FileInfo constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.fileinfo.aspx)

Put your code where you passing path in try block and catch the exception in catch block like this

```
try
{
    // Your code goes here
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
   // If exception raise compiler comes here.. 
}
```

For more read about [Try catch Blocks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
       fileSystemWatcher1.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
       DialogResult resDialog = dlgOpenDir.ShowDialog();
       if (resDialog.ToString() == "OK")
       {
           fileSystemWatcher1.Path = dlgOpenDir.SelectedPath;
           textBox1.Text = dlgOpenDir.SelectedPath;
       }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah well i got the "ArgumentException was unhandled" So he's saying there is no path. Which is normal but i want it to not give that error. My filewatcher starts watching immediatly but at the beginning there shouldn't be a path chosen.

Comment: So put it in try catch block, it will simply handle the exception and app will not crash if no path is choosen for first time

Comment: What do you exactly mean? Can you send in a code example? (I just started with C# a week ago.)

Comment: What should i put in the exception? And should it be like this? : 
            try
            {
                fileSystemWatcher1.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
    
            }

Comment: did you go through link provided for try catch ? It is basic concept in c#. Please go through this.. in try block put the code part which you think can raise exception.

Comment: What should i put in the exception? Not clear what you wanna says

Comment: yes i read it but i dont really get the concept of it. Cant you just give an example of how to do it with my code?

Comment: rene it crashes at:" fileSystemWatcher1.IncludeSubdirectories = true;" when i click on the first browse button and it crashes at:"fileSystemWatcher2.IncludeSubdirectories = true;" when i click on the second. I think because at the beginning the path is empty